# Outputting Page Content in Two Places

Tags: customization, navigation

I am working on a site for a client that is going to be structured very similarly to a store (though without the e-commerce capabilities). I am getting a bit hung up on how to output page content in two places. I'll explain. The site structure will be as follows:

- Windows

  - Casement Windows
  - Double Hung Windows

    - Brand A
    - Brand B

You can see here the windows are organized by *type* of window. Other navigation will have the opposite (by *brand*) where it will go Windows > Brand A > Double Hung Windows. My plan is to have each window product be its own page in WordPress, but I need a way to output it that page content in two places. In one place it will have the *brand* navigation and the other will have the *type* navigation. Any ideas on the best way to do this?

Comment: Two taxonomy terms seems the obvious way to go.

Comment: @vancoder Can you explain a bit more? Do you mean make each product as a post and then group them with both categories & tags (or other custom taxonomies) and output them that way?

Comment: Make each product a post (a CPT if you like), and associate 2 new taxonomies with it: _brand_ and _type_. This give you lots of flexibility in how you organize and present your posts. No tags are necessary.

Comment: @vancoder Great idea. I wasn't thinking of it that way, but that can be very powerful. Thanks!

Comment: The codex is your friend: [custom taxonomies](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies#Custom_Taxonomies)

Comment: @vancoder Posted your comment as an answer since it looks like that solved the OP's question. This way it gives this question some closure.

Answer (score 1):

As per [vancoder](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/26778/vancoder)'s comment under the OP's question:

> Make each product a post (a [Custom Post Type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Post_Types) if you like), and associate two new taxonomies with it: `brand` and `type`. This give you lots of flexibility in how you organize and present your posts. No tags are necessary.
>
> The codex is your friend: [Custom Taxonomies](https://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies#Custom_Taxonomies).